# Building Android Automotive emulator with bluetooth support

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-automotive

I've been trying to build an android automotive emulator to enable Bluetooth support. There are instructions at https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/start/passthrough.
However, the instructions leave quite many blanks and I would need advice from someone who is more experienced in making android custom builds.

**System:**

I'm building on a separate Linux computer, but I'm planning to use the AVD image on windows. I'm building an x86 64-bit variant.

**Current status:**

I have built an android AVD image, and I have built a custom goldfish-kernel-54 (without modifications), as specified in the previous section of the linked instructions. I'm able to run the image in the emulator. Now I will need to add Bluetooth support.

**Problems:**

I will quote the instructions and explain what I have done. I will **bold** the parts which I'm unsure of or which got me stuck.

Kernel:

> 1. Add the missing `btusb.ko` to your kernel:

There is no "goldfish_defconfig" file in that repo. However, there is file "common/arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig". **Is that the correct file?**

Guest android:

> 1. In the `vendor.mk` file, include the Linux native HIDL and several permissions:

Modified file "device/generic/goldfish/vendor.mk", should be ok.

> 2. Create a one-way path property to switch out the HIDL such that it uses a Linux native HIDL implementation

The instructions tell me to modify files "selinux/common/domain.te" and "selinux/common/property_contexts". However, there is no folder "selinux". I modified files "device/generic/goldfish/sepolicy/common/property_contexts" and "device/generic/goldfish/sepolicy/common/property_contexts". **Are these files correct?**

> 3. Whenever a property qemu.preferred.bt.service is set to pass through, you'll switch out the HIDL implementation

```
service btlinux-1.1 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.bluetooth@1.1-service.btlinux
  class hal
  user bluetooth
  group bluetooth net_admin net_bt_admin
  capabilities NET_ADMIN NET_RAW SYS_NICE
  disabled

on property:qemu.preferred.bt.service=passthrough
  stop vendor.bluetooth-1-1
  start btlinux-1.1
```

**This is the part where I'm completely stuck.** What am I supposed to do with the provided code snippet? Should I modify some existing file or add new file, and where?

> 4. Add a Bluetooth configuration file to get full features, such as on a real USB device

```
hal/bluetooth/bdroid_buildcfg.h

#ifndef _BDROID_BUILDCFG_H
#define _BDROID_BUILDCFG_H
#define BTM_DEF_LOCAL_NAME "gCar Emulator"
#define BTA_AV_SINK_INCLUDED TRUE
/* Handsfree device */
#define BTA_DM_COD {0x26, 0x04, 0x08}
#endif
```

**Here I'm stuck as well.** What should I do with the provided code? Which file should I modify?

> 5. Modify the `BoardConfig.mk` file to determine where the configuration file is saved

I modified file "device/google_car/avd_car/avd_car_device/BoardConfig.mk" (created in earlier phase when following given instructions). **Is that the correct file, or should I have modified some file in goldfish folder?**

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

There are some modification you need to do

> There is no "goldfish_defconfig" file in that repo. However, there is
> file "common/arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig". Is that the correct
> file?

As per the document, it is mentioned **goldfish_defconfig.fragment** which is in *common-modules/virtual-device*

> Modified file "device/generic/goldfish/vendor.mk", should be ok.

Yes, it is correct file if you are using google provided AAOS emulator

> The instructions tell me to modify files "selinux/common/domain.te"
> and "selinux/common/property_contexts". However, there is no folder
> "selinux". I modified files
> "device/generic/goldfish/sepolicy/common/property_contexts" and
> "device/generic/goldfish/sepolicy/common/property_contexts". Are these
> files correct?

Yes, these are correct files

> This is the part where I'm completely stuck. What am I supposed to do
> with the provided code snippet? Should I modify some existing file or
> add new file, and where?

There is a rc file named **android.hardware.bluetooth@1.1-service.btlinux.rc** which is in *system/bt/vendor_libs/linux/interface/* folder

> Here I'm stuck as well. What should I do with the provided code? Which
> file should I modify?

A file **bdroid_buildcfg.h** which is in *build/make/target/board/mainline_arm64/bluetooth/bdroid_buildcfg.h*

> I modified file
> "device/google_car/avd_car/avd_car_device/BoardConfig.mk" (created in
> earlier phase when following given instructions). Is that the correct
> file, or should I have modified some file in goldfish folder?

You can use same **vendor.mk** file to have configuration which is in *device/generic/goldfish/vendor.mk*

After build goldfish kernel you need to copy drivers and kernel image

```
cp goldfish-android11-5.4/out/android11-5.4/dist/bzImage prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86_64/5.4/kernel-qemu2
cp goldfish-android11-5.4/out/android11-5.4/dist/*.ko prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86_64/5.4/ko/
```

Build emulator and run. I hope you will able to connect BT devices